# Spivak: What is an example of polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree $<n$ that are equal up to order $n$ at $a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, taylor-expansion

**What is an example of polynomials $P$ and $Q$ of degree $<n$ that are equal up to order $n$ at $a$?**

The only one I can think of currently is $P(x)=Q(x)=0$. Is there another example?

To provide context about how this question came about, in Spivak's *Calculus*, it is defined that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal up to order $n$ at $a$ if

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-g(x)}{(x-a)^n}=0$$

Then we see the following theorems

> **Theorem 3** Let $P$ and $Q$ be two polynomials in $x-a$ of degree $\leq n$, and suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are equal up to order $n$ at
> $a$. Then $P=Q$.
>
> **Corollary** Let $f$ be n-times differentiable at $a$, and suppose that $P$ is a polynomial in $(x-a)$ of degree $\leq n$, which equals
> $f$ up to order $n$ at $a$. Then $P=P_{n,a,f}$.

where $P_{n,a,f}$ is the n-th order Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $a$.

**Why does he consider polynomials that can have a degree $<n$?**

That it, in the context of Theorem 3, is there an example of $P$ and $Q$ of degree $<n$ that are equal up to order $n$ at $a$?

For example, if $P(x)=2x^2$ and $Q(x)=x^2$, then

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{2x^2-x^2}{x^3}=\infty$$

ie $P$ and $Q$ are not equal up to order $3$ at $0$.

Comment: Right. You still need $P=Q$, as Spivak asserts.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's examples, but because of Theorem 3, they will all be just equal to eachother. For instance, set $n = 2$ and $p(x) = x = q(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I reached that conclusion just before you wrote this answer!

Comment: I guess I should have asked, is there an example of two different polynomials of degree $<n$ that are equal up to order $n$, but Theorem 3 rules this out as well.